# When training a model to estimate travel time, should I prefer estimates or actuals as my training data?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, distance

Let's say I'm training a model that predicts how long it takes me to walk from my front door to several locations in my neighbourhood. I've gathered data about the distance of these destinations, the speed at which I travel, etc. What I want to do now is add a new variable: whether I need to be on the ground floor of my destination, or whether I need to take the elevator when I get there. Of course, taking the elevator means my travel time will be longer.

```
 Time   Destination   Elevator (est.)   Elevator (act.)  
 ------ ------------- ----------------- ----------------- 
    10   A             no                no               
    13   A             yes               yes              
    11   A             no                no               
    14   A             no                yes              
    24   B             no                no
```

The problem is this: my estimation at departure is not always correct. Sometimes I will think my destination is the ground floor, but when I get there I see I actually have to go to the 3rd floor.

While training my model, I have both the estimates and the actuals available. But when I'm using the model to predict my travel time, I only have the estimates, of course.

My question is: should I prefer to train my model based on the estimates, or on the actuals? I know I could use both, or try both options and see what works best, but I'm looking for a theoretical answer (which is also why my example is a hypothetical case).

Moreover, if you know of any generic dataset on which I could perform such an analysis to compare the results, I'd be very interested.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a data-science answer than a statistical one, however: Don't use the actuals. There are two reasons:

1. By training your model on a dataset where one variable only has noise in actual use of the model, that variable will be given a higher weight in model-training than it should. Your training set should reflect actual data as much as possible.
2. By using actuals you would miss out on the predictive effect Destination+Elevator(est.) has on Elevator(act.).